# yamlMapper.readValue concatenate value with next attribute name causing InvaidFormatException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I have this method that maps a yaml configuration file to a class , but the mapping apparently is not OK, as shown in the bellow image, instead of mapping 60 to the `default` attribute it concatenates the next attribute name which causes an exception as `default` is an `int` and the retrieved value is a `string`.
Does anyone have any clue about why this is happening?

I tried adding a `\n` after 60 to force a line break without success. ( it was working fine until I updated the file , changed 30 to 60 in defaultLangId  ).

The Yaml file content :

```
defaultLangId : 60
  - code: AR
    label: ar
last-result-index : 120
```

My config calss :

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class XXXXXConfiguration {
    private int defaultLangId;
    private List<CodeLabel> cities;
    private int lastResultIndex;

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line after `60` is more indented. This causes YAML to read it as continuation of the scalar `60`, resulting in `60 - code` (for `-` to be considered a sequence item indicator, it must not be *inside* a scalar). Only when `:` is encountered, the value is finalized because `:` can end a scalar.

Your class indicates that you want to give a sequence that is to be loaded into the field `cities`; you need to give the key `cities` in your YAML for that:

```yaml
defaultLangId : 60
cities:
  - code: AR
    label: ar
last-result-index : 120
```